# Profiling add-ons in firefox

Tags: firefox, performance, firefox-extensions, internet-explorer-9, profiling

One new feature of ie9 I like is that it alerts you to which add-ons are making your browser run slowly. Is there a way to get access to similar information in firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way currently for Firefox to profile it's extensions without a significant overhead due to the way the Extensions API is built.

This extension will tell you a bit more about your startup times: [About Startup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-startup/)

<s>And Mozilla conducts regular tests on the addons every week. [Here's the listing of the slowest addons (updated weekly)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/performance/)</s>
<sub>*editor's Note: it appears that Mozilla is no longer publishing this.*</sub>

And if you want more info from the mozilla team, [here you go](https://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2011/04/01/improving-add-on-performance/) and [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Expose_Add-on_Performance).

Comment: [update]

Here is more info: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Expose_Add-on_Performance